# A question concerns prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

I have arrived to this conjecture in my work, I am not sure that is true or false. So I would appreciate if someone give a counterexample or prove it.

My question: Let n be a non-prime such that n-1 be a prime. Is it true that there exist a prime p such that n-p is a prime as well?

Comment: This is exactly the special case of Goldbach's Conjecture for even numbers that are 1 more than an odd prime.

Comment: Could you give some more details about the work where this question arose?

Comment: In Goldbach's day, the number 1 counted as a prime, hence the clean conjecture that "every even number is the sum of two (old-fashioned) primes."  The modern version, namely that every even number is the sum of two (modern) primes, is stronger exactly by the gap which is the OP's conjecture, hence some natural interest.

Comment: retagged as open problem.

Comment: Deal all thank you so much for you answers. Actually I have arrived to this question in group theory and I have never thought  that is an old open problem. I would appreciate, if you let me know any approach concerns this special case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjecture that any even number (greater than 4) is the sum of two odd primes is well-known to be open.  You are asking about a special case that is also open.

Comment: In view of David Feldman's comment, I add that the way this (and these types of question) are approached and seen nowadays this special case seems essentially as hard as the full conjecture.  